# Save a cell array full of structs into mat file

Tags: matlab

How can I save a cell array full of structs into a mat file in matlab? When I try this code:

```
save('fileName.mat', 'output', '-v7.3')
```

the mat file is full of cells that display `{0×0 double}`. I can store each struct individually, but not the whole cell array. I'm trying not to use dynamic variable names (storing structs one at a time in a loop will overwrite them because the variable name will always be the same).

Comment: If `output` is your cell array with structs, then it should be saved to the MAT-file such that `load fileName.mat` recreates the exact same cell array with all its contents. Please show a [mre] so that we can recreate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.- ALL variables smaller than 2GB**

I assume you have already checked this one.

Just 1 variable size > 2GB and save does not cherry pick, it just does not save anything at all.

I like the attempt mentioned in the question of saving variables one by one, so since it's also mentioned that there's a large amount of variables I am going to show how to do it with the **powerful MATLAB command** `evalin`

**1.- Simulating data**

```
N=20  % <100
L=[1:N];
vals=randi([-1000 1000],1,N);
```

**2.- Generating temporary support variables**

```
strL='//';
for k=1:1:numel(L)
    str0=['0' num2str(L(k))];
    if L(k)<10 
        strL=[strL;str0]; 
    else
        strL=[strL;num2str(L(k))];
    end
end
strL(1,:)=[];

for k=1:1:numel(L)
    str1=['store' strL(k,:) '=' num2str(vals(k))];
    evalin('base',str1)
end
```

20 temporary variables have been generated.

**3.- Start saving to .mat**

```
save file01.mat store01
for k=2:1:numel(L)
    str2=['save file01.mat store' strL(k,:) ' -append'];
    evalin('base',str2)
end
```

**4.- Clean the workspace**

`storeXX` variables are temporary, just for this specific storage into `.mat`

```
for k=1:1:numel(L)
    str3=['clear store' strL(k,:)];
    evalin('base',str3)
end
```

**5.- load `.mat` files with command load**

Self explained.

Command `load` allows to cherry pick any particular variable or group of variables in a given `.mat` file.

**6.- Merging loaded variables**

into the one structure mentioned in the question can be simplified in similar manner. Let me know if you would like an example on this point.

**7.- and clean up temporary variables**

Once struct rebuilt.

Again the particulars of the mentioned struct are unknown.

**Additional Comments**

**8.- Mathworks recommends always validate `evalin` input strings**

It's mentioned, for security considerations, to validate **ALL** `evalin` input strings, ALWAYS.

But since it seems to be obvious that the Ruby is in control of all the data, such security consideration does not apply to this particular case.

**YES** it's unwise to feed `evalin` with non-validated strings,

**BUT ANYWAY** isn't it unwise **FOR ANY COMMAND**, to feed them non-validated data ?!?

**Validating inputs is not an `evalin` only consideration, it's common sense FOR ANY COMMAND when handling critical data.**

Don't we all check what's on the pizza before going for it?

**9.- Do not build strings in `evalin` input field**

It's also recommended to use

```
evalin('base',expression)
```

as shown above in this answer, instead of building strings in the same `evalin` input field, for instance

```
evalin('base',['output=' expression])
```

Aagain **common sense**: that should the most common of the senses.

build the string first, this way it's easy, or should be easy to validate (or put aside/ flag / reject) it,
and then if valid data use `evalin`

`evalin` **a mighty MATLAB command indeed that allows to write code that writes code.**

Comment: In a script, `evalin('base',str1)` is the same as `eval(str1)`. There is no reason to prefer the one over the other, other than that the one is shorter to type. In any other context (usually we write code in functions), the two are different: one evaluates in the base workspace, the other one in the local (current) one. In your usage, it is this second one you must use, because `str1` is declined in the local workspace. So, your code should use `eval`, not `evalin`.

Comment: Yes, `eval` and friends are powerful and sometimes incredibly useful. But because it makes code harder to read (and thus maintain, debug), and makes code slower, you want to use it only if there is no other recourse. In this case, you could use [`matfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.matfile.html) to write values to a MAT-file without creating those variables in the workspace first. That would result in faster code that is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Good comment Chris, I like evalin. I tested it with evalin and it works. My answer works ok. I'd like to now focus on other questions. Thanks for your remark. Please show use how to do it with eval.

Comment: This worked, thank you for your thought out solution! Cris, I have heard that evals are a bad idea to use, but I am only going to run this code once to store data after my algorithm is done, so it doesn't need to be efficient. However, if you can recommend a different way to do this I would appreciate it. The root of my problem is that the total cell array is 31.8 GB (I was not aware of the limit lol), so I do need to store structs one at a time.